# How do I stop the CORS error when accessing a PHP file in a parent domain using AJAX in a file on a subdomain?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

I have a PHP file on a subdomain, and within that file, I want to use `Javascript` and `Ajax` to send information to a PHP file on the parent domain (to update my database). However, I receive the error that the request has been blocked by `CORS` (which makes sense, I understand why). Is there a simple way to solve this?

I have tried putting document.domain = "example.com" in the javascript on the subdomain file, but obviously I can't put this in the file on the parent domain because it is a PHP file with no javascript. Just putting that line in the subdomain file has not worked.

```
file1: area1.example.com/settings.php

<?php
print '
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateTable(Info)
{
$.ajax({url: "https://example.com/ajax/update-table.php", type: "POST", data: {id: 1, info: Info}});
}
</script>';
?>


file2: example.com/ajax/update-table.php

<?php
$query = '
Update `Table`
SET `Table`.`field` = "'.$_POST['info'].'"
WHERE `Table`.`id` = '.$_POST['id'];
db_op($query);
?>
```

All I want is for the database to be updated, but I keep receiving the same CORS error. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: _“Is there a simple way to solve this?”_ - yes: Allow CORS. (And if your next question would immediately be, how to do that, please go research it first.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try set header at file in parent domain.

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com");`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You can solve this as @Berdnikov mentioned with the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. You can either do this by using the PHP header function like Berdnikov suggested or you can use .htaccess,

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin <value>
</IfModule>
```

Where `<value>` can be one of a specific path match i.e. `http://example.com` or you can wildcard for any host with `*`

#### Here's why,

When a browser makes a resource sharing request to a different domain, the browser first launches a [Preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) request which uses the OPTIONS protocol to determine what the client request is permitted to do. This includes `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` too.

I am making the following advisories on the code you posted above,

1. Note that from observing your code, its clear there is no active authentication on the request ([WSSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security), Api keys or any stateless authentication mechanism), unless you are using a shared COOKIE of sorts I feel obligated to at least let you know that this request is not protected,
2. The SQL you have pasted is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), you are not escaping anything and inserting the input directly into the query, which is highly dangerous for your application integrity.

Good luck and happy coding

Answer (score -1):

I really hope I am giving you proper advice here, but have a look at the Content Security Policy header.....

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy

I think you need to use something like this to whitelist the domain....

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; data: https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/* 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I stand to be corrected on this - I ran across this issue with a cordova app I was building a while ago and I think this was how I fixed it.